# How to invert this function when the argument e is small?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, parametric-functions, approximation

I need to find an analytical solution the following equation for `e` in terms of `n` and `p`

```
kldFunc[x_, y_] := x Log[x/y] + (1 - x) Log[(1 - x)/(1 - y)];

kldFunc[p + e, p]==n (* with the following constraints*) 1>p>0&&1-p >e>0
```

This seems hard if not impossible.

I will also be satisfied to find a function `f[p_,e_]<= kldFunc[p + e, p]` for the same constraints, for which the equation

```
f[p,e]==n
```

can be solved for `e` analytically.

How should I appraoch this in Mathematica? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am guessing `\[Epsilon]` is `e` in your equations?

Comment: Is `\[Epsilon]` small? Maybe the function `InverseSeries` could help but I did not try

Comment: yes `e` is indeed epsilon. I am trying to solve for e. Ill look into InverseSeries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @userrandrand suggests, series-expand the function in $\epsilon$ and then [invert the series](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseSeries.html):

```
kldFunc[x_, y_] = x Log[x/y] + (1 - x) Log[(1 - x)/(1 - y)];

s = Series[kldFunc[p + ε, p], {ε, 0, 3}] // FullSimplify
(*    ε^2/(2 p - 2 p^2) + 1/6 (1/(-1 + p)^2 - 1/p^2) ε^3 + O[ε]^4    *)

ee[p_, n_] = Assuming[0 < p < 1, InverseSeries[s, n] // FullSimplify] // Normal
(*    1/3 n (1 - 2 p) + Sqrt[n] Sqrt[2 p - 2 p^2]    *)
```

Let's try it out for $p=0.3$ and $n=0.05$:

```
ee[0.3, 0.05]
(*    0.15158043412856104    *)
```

Back-substitute to check:

```
kldFunc[p + ε, p] /. {p -> 0.3, ε -> 0.15158043412856104}
(*    0.0508472    *)
```

You'll get more accurate results by using a higher-order series-expansion in `s`. To get an idea of the accuracy, try

```
Series[kldFunc[p + ε, p] /. ε -> ee[p, n], {n, 0, 2}] // FullSimplify
(*    n + (1/9 + 1/(18 p - 18 p^2)) n^2 + O[n](5/2)    *)
```